# Read and head data from Geofabrik OSM

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geolocation, geofabrik

I am trying to read and head all the data from geofabrik specific country using this code:

```
from pyrosm import OSM, get_data

df = get_data("country_name")

df.head()
```

But I am getting this kind of error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'head'
```

How can you simple read and then export data from downloaded osm.pbf file to CSV format for example?

Answer (score 0):

I think get_data actually downloads the data to your machine and returns the filepath of where the data is saved. So df here is actually a string filepath. You can check by doing print(df) to see what its like.

To read the data in try:

```
osm = pyrosm.OSM(df) # here df is the filepath you generated above

custom_filter = {'amenity': True}

data = osm.get_pois(custom_filter=custom_filter)
```

data is the one you want